# Delphi IDE search using regular expressions

Tags: regex, delphi, search, ide

I am in Delphi 10.2.2 Tokyo and trying to do a simple  regular expression search. I'm sure I've done this before but it's not working.

It doesn't work whether I `Ctrl-F` search in the current source file **or** I `Ctrl-Shift-F` Find in Files.

I have researched this to make sure I understood the special characters & their meanings.

Anyway, search string `fun.*e` I assume will find any `fun`ction declaration with an `e` in its name.

It finds nothing! I have tried a variety of searches like this - they **all** are finding nothing.

`Case sensitive` unchecked.

`Whole words` unchecked.

`Search selection` unchecked.

`Entire scope` checked. (for `Ctrl-F`, in current source file, search)

And, of course, `Regular expression` checked.

If I `Search in Files` I get the `Search string 'fun.*e' not found` popup. Period.

However, if I `Ctrl-F` I am seeing (current unit) **31 matches found** in dark green down in the "search bar" and if I scroll through the unit, I am seeing the matches (highlighted in orange). But the cursor does not move to the first (or any) match. If I hit `F3` immediately after doing the search (and seeing **31 matches found**) I am getting the **Search Match Not Found** `Restart search from the beginning of the file?` popup. And if I say `Yes` I am back to seeing `Search string 'fun.*e' not found`!

I don't know if I might've changed some setting or option or whatever. I cannot imagine that I have. But I need to use Regular Expressions for searching.

FWIW, "normal" searches are working fine (whether `Regular expression` is checked or not).

Answer (score 1):

I had Tools | Options | Editor Options | BRIEF regular expressions on.

Turning this off has fixed my issue.